# In MongoDB when searching with multiple parameters how to know which parameter matched

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

For example if I have a Mongoose schema with fields like title and body:

```
var Datum = db.model('Datum', {
    title:      { type: String },
    body:       { type: String },
}
```

Now I want to search both fields for a substring, I can do something like this:

```
Datum.find({
  { $or: [ { title: substring }, { body: substring } ] }
},
function(results) {
  console.log(results)
})
```

but I'd like to give title a bigger weight, so for two entries, if one matched in `title`, another matched in `body`, I'd like the former to be returned in a higher order.

Is there anyway for mongoDB to return which condition matched in each result? Or do I have to search the database multiple times for this purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you create text indexes in MongoDB the default weight assigned to each indexed field is 1.
however if you want to give a particular field more weight you can include weights option when you create index and that will do the trick for you.

```
{
db.yourCollection.createIndex(
   {
     title: "text",
     body: "text",

   },
   {
     weights: {
       title: 10,
       body: 5
     },
     name: "myIndex"
   }
 )
}
```

Comment: an example: db.articles.find(
   { $text: { $search: "cake" } },
  **{ score: { $meta: "textScore" } }**
)

Answer (score 0):

afaik there is no function like match rate for non text indexes. (see satish chennupati answer for text index)

To cover that, mongo response need to be processed client side, to avoid expensive server calls, and depends on document number one check or loop need to be executed.